# Bounding simple series involving binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $r \ge 1$. What is a simple argument to show the following two inequalities:
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{m=1}^n 2^m \binom{n}{m}^2 \Big( \frac{en}{m}\Big)^{-5rm} &\le n^{-r} \\
 \sum_{m=1}^n \binom{n}{m}^2 \Big( \frac{2 \alpha n}{m}\Big)^{-4rm} &\le n^{-r}, \quad \text{when} \;\alpha \ge \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} 
\end{align*}